# Azure Service Fabric Previous Installation after CleanFabric

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to reinstall Azure Service Fabric after (probably incorrectly) running clean on one of the nodes in a cluster.

I've run CleanFabric.ps1 and got the following result:

```
FabricInstallerSvc is already removed.
FabricSetup.exe is no longer in FabricCodePath. Uninstall may have already run.
```

When I run TestConfiguration.ps1 for a one-machine node I get the following result:

```
    Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.WindowsServer.5.3.301.9590> .\TestConfiguration.ps1 -Clust
    erConfigFilePath .\ClusterConfig.Unsecure.DevCluster.json
    Trace folder already exists. Traces will be written to existing trace folder: Microsoft.Azu
    re.ServiceFabric.WindowsServer.5.3.301.9590\DeploymentTraces

    Previous Fabric installation detected on machine localhost. Please clean the machine.
    Run Test-ServiceFabricConfiguration or TestConfiguration.ps1 to validate configuration & environment state. Best Practic
    es Analyzer hit validation error(s).


    LocalAdminPrivilege        : True
    IsJsonValid                : True
    IsCabValid                 : True
    RequiredPortsOpen          : True
    RemoteRegistryAvailable    : True
    FirewallAvailable          : True
    RpcCheckPassed             : True
    NoConflictingInstallations : True
    FabricInstallable          : False
    Passed                     : False
```

I've searched around trying to find a solution to this or some documentation on CleanFabric and have been unsuccessful. Anyone know how to completely clean the machine to reinstall Service Fabric on it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In case others run into this issue on a local machine running windows here's what I did to fix it: Make sure the clean fabric was indeed run first. Then go to the key: `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Service Fabric]`

 and make sure paths that it references are manually deleted (if you run into process running files you're trying to delete just go into safe mode then kill it all) after you cleared all the directories out delete the key itself. This allowed me to reinstall a new cluster on the nodes.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. Normally the CleanFabric script should do this, but I also encountered that the leftover registry key was causing problems. Deleting the key helped...